# function pointers for std::unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, std

There are sites like this one:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/

That say, one can provide a function pointer, instead of a class, for the `Hash` and `Pred` argument of the `std::unordered_map` class template. However, there are no examples, and I haven't managed to get this feature to work, if it is possible at all. Nonworking example:

```
bool unordered_eq(const char* const s1, const char* const s2)
{
  return !std::strcmp(s1, s2);
}

std::size_t unordered_hash(char const* s)
{
  return std::hash<std::string>()(s);
}

std::unordered_map<char const*, std::string,
  unordered_hash, unordered_eq> hashmap;
```

Comment: If you want to use strings as keys, why not use `std::string`? It works with string literals as well.

Comment: Just an example, the `Key` can be anything. I know the answer in the mean time anyway, one can use `decltype(&unordered_hash)` and `decltype(&unordered_eq)` as `Hash` and `Pred`. The site is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> That say, one can provide a function pointer, instead of a class

No, that's a misunderstanding. You can provide a function pointer instead of a function **object** to the **constructor**. The template parameter is still a type - in this case the type of a function pointer. So, you have to write

```
typedef unordered_map<
            char const*, string,
            size_t(*)(char const*), // type for hashing
            bool(*)(char const*, char const*) // type for equality
        > yourmaptype;

yourmaptype hm (
        4, // minimum number of buckets
        &unordered_hash, // function address for hashing
        &unordered_eq, // function address for equality
    );
```

Your standard library defines a default value for the first parameter but this default value is not standardized. It seems there is no way of keeping your vendor-specific default value for n and at the same time set the functors' values. My use of 4 is rather arbitrary here.

You should consider the use of default-constructible function objects instead. Not only this will allow you to get away without specifying the minimim bucket size, it also will be potentially faster since functors are *much* easier to inline for the compiler.

Comment: Just for the record, `gcc` uses the default value of `10` for `n`.